# Updating Pandas Dataframe from Matplotlib animation function

Tags: matplotlib

I have a simple working Matplotlib animation which increment two lists, xs[] and ys[]:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xs = []
ys = []
def animate(i):
    xs.append(i)
    ys.append(i**2)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs,ys)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Now, if I try to use a Pandas DataFrame instead of the lists I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment
```

Using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = []
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y'])

def animate(i):
    new_row = {'x':i,'y':i**2}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    ax.plot(df['x'],df['y'])
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

How can I update the external Pandas DataFrame from within Matplotlib FuncAnimation without making the DataFrame Global?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, I ended up declaring a global data[] variable inside my animation function:

```
def animate(i):
    global data
```